# Firebase Realtime Database Download Data Size Problem

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
1.DatabaseReference db=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
1.Query query = db.orderByKey().equalTo(uid);
   
2.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").orderByChild("token").equalTo(toKen)
```

Does any one of the above two codes written in Java Android Studio send the entire **"users"** node of Realtime Database to the client Android App or Only the the Fetched Records will be send to the client Android App. It Seems like that it sends the complete **"users"** node to the client Android App, because my realtime database bill is quite high and customers are low.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for `orderByChild()`. To get the child node where the value of `uid` is equal to passed UID, try this:

```
DatabaseReference db=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

Query query = db.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(uid);
```

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sort_data) says,

| Method | Usage |
| --- | --- |
| orderByChild | Order results by the value of a specified child key or nested child path. |
| orderByKey | Order results by child keys. |

The second query looks fine and should fetch the node where the value of `token` is equal to the supplied token.

Comment: Does any one of my above two code will send the entire users node data to client side, because my download bytes size is quite high??

Comment: @Shubhendu neither of the queries will send the whole users node. Just correct the first query. If my answer was helpful you can accept it by clicking the tick icon and upvote by the up arrow icon else feel free to ask further queries.

Comment: @Shubhendu If you don't use the `orderByChild()` and just query on the Database Reference, then the whole users not will be sent.

Answer (score 1):

If the download size is higher than you'd expect based on the number of query results, check if you've [defined an index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) on the `token` property. If no such index exists, Firebase will download all data under `users` to the client, and perform the sort/filter there. If an index *is* declared, the ordering/filtering is done on the server.